# Oracle SQL Pivot Table from one column into two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table with two columns PersonId and Job that needs to pivot to turn the Job column into multiple columns based on the three jobs in the table. Then once pivoted each job should say "yes" or "no" in the column if the PersonId has that job associated to them.

Example Table:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the "dynamic" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select personid,
  max(case when job = 'a' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as a,
  max(case when job = 'b' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as b,
  max(case when job = 'c' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as c
from tablename
group by personid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b56f398b3e68a9417024a44ef6ca49be).
Results:

```
| personid | a   | b   | c   |
| -------- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1        | yes | yes | no  |
| 2        | yes | no  | no  |
| 3        | no  | no  | yes |
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Do you know why I might be getting the error "FROM keyword not found where expected" when I run it? Here's the below code i'm using: select emplid,
max(case when acad_career = 'UGRD' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as 'UGRD',
  max(case when acad_career = 'GRAD' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as 'GRAD',
  max(case when acad_career = 'CERT' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as 'CERT'
FROM (
select distinct emplid, acad_career
from sysadm.adtl
)group by emplid

Comment: This is an Oracle error. Check the edited demo link.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the aliases UGRD, GRAD and CERT.

Comment: That was the issue, it worked after removing them. Thank you!